# Displaying data from an .txt file that's on an URL - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, object, fetch

I want to display data from a .txt file that's uploaded on an URL, on my React app. The URL is part of a JSON object that I'm "fetching" in a function using Fetch. I'm storing that Object into my state. So if I want to display the URL, I would do something like :

```
{this.state.result.URL}
```

Now I'd like to display the contents that are stored in this URL along with my other data. I've tried using  tag for this. Something like this:

```
       <p>
       <object width="910" height="180" type="text/plain" data= 
       {this.state.result.Introduction} border="0" 
       style={Objectstyle}></object>
       </p>
```

The problem I'm facing with this is that the text that appears on my screen is inside a box that has a scroll bar. If I play around with the height and width, I'm able to remove the box and the scroll bar, but the font is a very .txt style font. It looks very different from the rest of the page.

My question is how do I make that font look as same as the default font of my app. Or is there a better way to load this text from the URL? Like storing it into a variable and then just displaying the text using that variable? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Please check these images to see the difference in the fonts and the scrollbar. [image: Image with the default web page font][image: contents from the .txt file's font]

Answer (score 0):

Are you fixing height in px,
Try height =100% , I think it will work

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work. The font is still significantly different than the other web elements on the page. It's the font you get when you type in notepad.